# 'LOCAL_TARGET_DATABASE must not already exist' error

Tags: sql, database, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm attempting to pull a remote heroku database to my computer so that I can browse it with SQlite, but I keep recieving the following error: `LOCAL_TARGET_DATABASE must not already exist`. How would I go about removing the local target database it's referring to? Is this the database associated with the local version of my app? Won't removing that database cause errors when I test the app locally?

Answer (score -1):

According to the [heroku library source code](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb#L287-L290), I would guess the issue is that the local database should not exist.

The local database is the one referenced by your application configuration, or the one you mention when you invoke the command

```
pg:pull <REMOTE_SOURCE_DATABASE> <LOCAL_TARGET_DATABASE>
```

(that is the second argument)

Comment: Where can i find this local database, and will deleting it cause problems when I'm testing my app locally?

Comment: The local database it's likely to be your local app database, the one you set in the development environment of your app.

Comment: And there's no way for me to have heroku pull to another separate database locally? I want to be able to continue testing the db locally.